# Find/Replace JSON Keys with Apex

Tags: apex, json, bulk-api, parsing

I'm stuck preparing a JSON body for a request. I am pretty new to JSON and don’t fully understand the parsing class syntax, but I conceptually understand what I’m trying to do.

**Overall Goal:** My roadblock is part of a larger goal to push records from Salesforce Org A to Salesforce Org B. I am attempting to utilize Bulk API v1 and send the records as a JSON body. I have successfully sent a request to initialize a Bulk Data Job, with the correct headers, sObject parameter, content type, etc. Both with Postman and Anonymous Apex, this is working and I can successfully init a Batch Job and pass JSON data that I specifically write.

My goal now is to automatically generate the JSON body programmatically.

Consulting documentation, I understand that for a given sObject, my JSON body needs to be in this format

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Account 1",
        "Custom_Field__c": "value here"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Account 2",
        "Custom_Field__c": "another value"
    }
]
```

My issue is getting my sObject query in Apex into this format. I have seen several ideas around maps and JSON parsing, which admittedly I don't fully understand yet. However I am really close:

I built a custom class, and looped my list of sObject records and created "records" in my generic class/object. However, I cannot set the names of my object variables (ie, fields) with “__c”. My solution was to set them with a unique appendix (ie, _ccc) and then replace that with __c once it’s a JSON String.

**So, my current JSON string looks like this**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Account 1",
        "Custom_Field_ccc": "value here"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Account 2",
        "Custom_Field_ccc": "another value"
    }
]
```

And this is where I’m stuck. **I can’t figure out how to loop my JSON string and replace every instance of "_ccc" with "__c"**. One of the issues I can’t understand is that my entire JSON string is wrapped in an array, so some of the suggestions about turning this into a map and then using basic apex on the keys don’t translate exactly with the content of my string.

Comment: How did you 'build' your JSON string? Why are you not able to set the object variable with "__c"?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @HengkyIlawan I appreciate your question. I am building the JSON string by creating a custom class and a variable inside the class for each field of the sobject. Then, loop sobject collection and assign values to variables in my apex class. Problem was, I cannot name my class variables with a __c on the end. I am now thinking if I could build the JSON string another way without a class.

Comment: @SebastianKessel As described above, our goal is to move data from Salesforce Org A to Salesforce Org B in an ongoing basis using the Bulk API. BulkAPI demands the field names are exact in the JSON file, so I need to set JSON keys to field names in Org B. Currently I cannot set keys with "__c" appendix because I am building my JSON string from a apex class.

Comment: Is the JSON data not coming from a single object? Are you not able to use `JSON.serialize()`?

Comment: Further on @HengkyIlawan's point - SObjects themselves can easily be serialized to JSON. Just do something like ```List<Account> accounts  = new List<Account> { new Account(Name = 'Account 1', Custom_Field__c = 'value here'), new Account(Name = 'Account 2', Custom_Field__c = 'another value') }; System.debug(JSON.serialize(accounts));```. This will contain a little extra data (specifically the "attributes" property for each instance) but that could be managed easily enough I am sure.

Comment: Thanks @HengkyIlawan and PhilW, you are both helping me think through my approach. I was able to easily serialize a list of sObjects, however as you point out Phil, it contains several extra properties such as the Attributes property, and always brings the Id and RecordTypeId properties too. I couldn't figure out how to loop through that JSON string and remove those properties for each record, but at this point exploring that solution might be easier.